# Alter div content using jQuery and save result to variable

Tags: jquery, html

I have content on a page that contains ads. I need to be able to pull the content of this page using jQuery and strip the ads from the content. I have gotten this to work, but it also alters the elements on the page. I need to get a variable that contains a clean version of the html inside the div, but strip all of the ads.

I had hoped that something like this would work, but it doesnt. is there anything i can do to make it save the html of "postbody" with the changes from the "find/remove" method applied, without altering the live content on the page.

```
var content = jQuery('#postbody').find('.adsbygoogle').remove().html();
```

When i run the above command, it does what i want it to do, but it removes the content from the actual post on the page.

There also appears to be some code in the adsense library that prevents me from getting the page content, saving it to a placeholder. Altering the page, get the content without ads then replacing it all with the content from the placeholder variable.

Comment: clone it first? https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: I put .clone in before the .find and it didnt alter the code on the page, but the result was the adsense ad and no content. I want the reverse of this.

Comment: what if instead of remove you use hide() or add a display:none style attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$postbody = $("#postbody").clone();
$postbody.find('.adsbygoogle').remove();
return $postbody.html();
```